# Copying a union range with a last row value

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that is sort of working now but I've hit another snag. For some reason it is copying from the same sheet multiple times and pasting to the new workbook. I think this is due to my `NumRange + 100` perimeter I set because I couldnt get the LastRow variable to work.

```
Public Sub extractCol()

'Find FF&E Section, Add 3 rows and Identify relevant columns.

Dim rFind As Range, CRange As String, ERange As String, KRange As String, MRange As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim NumRange As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add ' Open new Workbook

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
With ws
    Set rFind = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="FF&E", LookAt:=xlWhole,     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rFind Is Nothing Then

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        NumRange = rFind.Row + 3 ' Find FF&E line and add three

        CRange = "C" & NumRange & ":" & "C" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column C
        ERange = "E" & NumRange & ":" & "E" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column E
        KRange = "K" & NumRange & ":" & "K" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column K
        MRange = "M" & NumRange & ":" & "M" & NumRange + 100 ' Define First 100 Lines in Column M

        Set range1 = Union(.Range(CRange), .Range(ERange), .Range(KRange), .Range(MRange)) ' Combine individual column ranges in to one selection
        range1.Copy ' Copy new combined range

        NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues ' Paste to new Workbook
        NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(range1.Rows.Count).Value = FindRoom(ws)

    End If
End With
Next ws

End Sub

Function FindRoom(ws As Worksheet)

shtName = ws.Name

Dim arr() As String
arr = VBA.Split(shtName, " ")

xCount = UBound(arr)
If xCount < 1 Then
    FindRoom = "Unknown"
Else
    FindRoom = arr(xCount)
End If
End Function
```

So I tried fixing it by doing the following;

```
            CRange = "C" & NumRange & ":" & "C" & LastRow
            ERange = "E" & NumRange & ":" & "E" & LastRow
            KRange = "K" & NumRange & ":" & "K" & LastRow
            MRange = "M" & NumRange & ":" & "M" & LastRow
```

But this causes an error on the following line;

```
range1.Copy
```

Any help on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I recognise that code. It was working wasn't it, and I can't see any obvious problem there. What is the value of `numrange` when it errors?

Comment: Hey SJR, indeed it's me again and yes it was working but on closer inspection I found that the output it was giving had multiples of a lot of the rows. I think this was down to the "Numrange +100" that I did which Isn't always true as in it's not always +100 to the end of the sheet. Hence why I have tried to introduce the LastRow variable so that I can give an exact end location on each sheet which should hopefully fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code and checking the values of the variables? What is the error on the copy line? Is the problem with a particular sheet?

Comment: Right I managed to fix it. When I change all to LastRow it seems to work. For some reason it doesn't like it when i was using Lastrow on some ranges and NumRange on others.. Not sure I understand what was happening but it's working now.